# String.Contains matches unexpected value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of objects and I'm looking there for object with specified taskname. Mostly it perform good without any problem. But.. if I'm looking for object which contains this in taskname:

> 31022000-1-00

It return me object with taskname:

> ** ******** 31021242-1-00

There is more cases with the same problem. But as I said mostly it return correct value.

My code:

```
if (ProjectTasks.Count(t => t.Name.Contains(task.Name)) == 1)
            {
                ProjectTask MatchingTask = ProjectTasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Contains(task.Name));

                UpdateTask(task, MatchingTask);
            }
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: This code does not return that object. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: That code *won't* return what you describe, unless your `task.Name` property contains only a subset of what you posted, eg `3202` instead of `31022000-1-00`. Post code that actually reproduces the problem and show the relevant data

Comment: Also note, this is `String.Contains`, not LINQ. If there is any problem, you could demonstrate it with a simple `"** ******** 31021242-1-00".Contains("31022000-1-00")`. This won't do what you describe though, which means that your data is not what you expect it to be

Answer (score -1):

You are using Contains, so the behavior is expected. If you need exact match, use Equals instead.

```
ProjectTask MatchingTask = ProjectTasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(task.Name));
if (MatchingTask != null)
{             
     UpdateTask(task, MatchingTask);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you act on the condition that there is only one task with a matching name? Could there be more? If not - you probably should refactor your code

```
var MatchingTask = ProjectTasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Contains(task.Name));
    if (MatchingTask !=null){
         UpdateTask(task, MatchingTask);             

 }
```